# "I always wear a shoe"

Tags: riddle

```
Cock-a-doodle-doo! My colour's any hue
Although I'm put upon the foot
I always wear a shoe.
```

---

*Source (this is not intended to be used to look up the answer, but is posted under [the policy on plagiarism of the Puzzle Stack Exchange website](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)):*

> Source: The Queenslander (discontinued in 1939), without any specific author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how this fits perfectly, but it seems it must be

> A sock

Cock-a-doodle-doo!

> Poetic license

My colour's any hue

> Socks come in all sorts of colours

Although I'm put upon the foot

> Well, you could put socks on your hands, but unless you're entertaining a baby you may come across as a little on the odd side

I always wear a shoe

> Well, not *always*; in fact mostly not - the socks on my feet right now are not, and neither are those in my sock drawer, or for that matter, those in my laundry basket